# Getting Upload file in PHP $_REQUEST

Tags: php, file, file-upload, php-5.4

I am receiving uploaded file in PHP **$_REQUEST** Super global , as per my knowledge **$_FILES** contains all the information of uploaded file and **$_REQUEST** contains **$_POST,$_GET,$_COOKIES**.

Also I am getting an empty $_FILES array for same request.

In PHP 4.3 version **$_REQUEST** contains file Information but I am using PHP version 5.4.11

How can it is possible?

Comment: You have to use $_FILES to get file information. it's removed from $_REQUEST in php 5+.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question so people don't misunderstand your question

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php):

> 4.3.0 $_FILES information was removed from $_REQUEST.

Comment: I believe he means even though he's using 5.4 PHP he's getting the files object in $_REQUEST

Comment: Sorry @Ekansh I misunderstood your question. Is it possible `register_globals` is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Got The answer , actually my colleague (android developer) sending that file after encoding base64 , so that’s why i think $_FILES is empty and $_REQUEST containing file content.